# Cant get the query to work

Tags: sql, oracle

Try to see which player scored the most goals.

```
Player_id
Goals.
```

I tried the following statement:

```
select player_id, sum(goals) as total
from matchstat
group by player_id
order by total desc limit 1;
```

But i get the error:

> SQL command not properly ended.

Does anyone see the problem with the query?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support the limit clause. Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT "player_id", 
               SUM("goals") AS total 
        FROM   matchstat 
        GROUP  BY "player_id" 
        ORDER  BY total DESC) a 
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 1
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a715b/1)

Comment: What gave you the clue that OP uses Oracle?

Comment: @PM77-1 [`SQL command not properly ended.`](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+command+not+properly+ended)